# Download a picture from certain URL with Python

Tags: python, image

I learned how to download a picture from a certain URL with python as:

```
import urllib
imgurl="http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg"
resource = urllib.urlopen(imgurl)
output = open("test.jpg","wb")
output.write(resource.read())
output.close()
```

and it worked well, but when i changed the URL to

```
  imgurl="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/96/242125326_607a826afe_o.jpg"
```

it did not work, and gave the information

```
File "face_down.py", line 3, in <module>
resource = urllib2.urlopen(imgurl)
File "D:\Python27\another\Lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "D:\Python27\another\Lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "D:\Python27\another\Lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
'_open', req)
File "D:\Python27\another\Lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "D:\Python27\another\Lib\urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "D:\Python27\another\Lib\urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] >
```

and I tried to open the latter image URL, and it could be shown as the former, I have no idea to solve it~~ help~~~~

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **requests** module. The response will be some bytes. So, you can iterate over those byte chunks and write to the file.

```
import requests

url = "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/96/242125326_607a826afe_o.jpg"
r = requests.get(url)
path = "filename.jpg"
with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r:
        f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Wow, I'll try this!

Comment: it still has error 10060, maybe the website cannot download TAT

Answer (score 0):

I looked up both of the addresses and the second one does not lead anywhere. That is probably the problem.

```
import urllib
imgurl="webpage url"
openimg = urllib.urlopen(imgurl) #opens image (prepares it)
img = open("test.jpg","wb") #opens the img to read it
img.write(openimg.read()) #prints it to the console
img.close() #closes img
```

Try the link again in your webpage and if it turns up with "webpage not available" that is probably the problem.

Comment: it still showed the errors, and i tried the original code then it works, so strange! Sometimes it works, and sometime it does not